# Camera gets inverted when turning 180 degrees vertically in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, euler-angles

When I am turning my camera 180 degrees vertically the horizontal input gets inverted

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FreeLookCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivity = 2.0f;

    private float rotationX = 0.0f;
    private float rotationY = 0.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        rotationY += mouseX * sensitivity;
        rotationX -= mouseY * sensitivity;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, rotationY, 0);
    }
}
```

I was trying to make a space movement system where the camera could look anywhere without any constraints.

Comment: Sounds like Gimbal lock. See: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html, specifically the section on Gimbal lock. Try to avoid Euler angles in favour of other methods in Quaternion: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html as these adjust for it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a global frame of reference for your axis rotations. Turning horizontally always results in the same rotation on the y axis no matter how the camera is oriented.

To make a truly free camera you need to rotate relative to the cameras current orientation. Doing so with typical euler angles gets complicated quickly and you'll run into the [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) effect. You can avoid all that by using quaternions.

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class FreeLookCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivity = 2.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
        float rotationX = - Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;

        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, rotationY, 0);
    }
}
```

Every frame this code takes in your Mouse movement turns it into a rotation using the familiar `Quaternion.Euler` function and adds it to the current rotation of the camera. To keep the explanation short, you can add two rotations by multiplying their quaternions (because matrix math).